# How to click a table row to display a new table?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to click a row data which will then display a new table with an external API.

I am using useEffect to fetch a URL which then goes into a ag-Grid-React table. If the user clicks on any row in a particular column, a new table should appear and replace the first table, based on another API.

I have Make, Model and Year as my three columns. When I click any row from the Model column, a new table should display with data on that selected Model.

Is there any general code/tutorials/documents or even pointers out there that could help with this issue?

I’ve tried looking at history API, filtering what I need, onClick event and so on, based on posts I’ve seen here.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by writing an onClick function on each rows of your Model column and then in that function, call your API and then render your table.

Something like this:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        // First API Call
        fetch(/* url */).then((response) => response.json()).then((response) => {
            setTableData(response);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        });
    }, []);

    const handleOnClick = (model) => {
        fetch(/* url based on {model} */).then((response) => response.json()).then((response) => {
            setTableData(response);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        });
    }

    if(tableData) {
        return (
            <div>
                /* ... */
                <td onClick={() => handleOnClick(/* model */)}>/* model */</td>
                /* ... */
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```